# Using Data sets in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

What is the best practice to use data sets instead of an observable collection in MVVM to bind to grids. is it OK to have a property of type DataSet on the view model? How is the design time data set in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the key concepts of the MVVM pattern is that the ViewModel is the "model of your view", it shapes your business model in such a way that it is easier to bind a UI (i.e. your View) to it.

You can certainly use a DataSet / DataTable to expose data from your ViewModel and bind it to your View. I don't see anything wrong with this approach. It is certainly valid MVVM!

Regarding design time data, it depends on how you are creating it. You cannot create a DataSet in XAML, so cannot use a XAML file within visual studio for your data. However, if you are programmatically creating design time data, i.e. within your ViewModel checking whether it is design-time, then creating data in your code, it will work just fine.